# Import existing CSS class in new DIV HTML tag

Tags: html, css, class, stylesheet

Lets say there is

```
.myButtonClass{
/*#style;*/
}
```

Now i have new

```
<div id="myid">
```

One way is i can have

```
<div id="myid" class="myButtonClass">
```

What if in my CSS i want to assign this class to div

```
div.myid{
/* assign existing class */
.myButtonClass
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: you can do that using jquery like `$('div#myid').addClass('myButtonClass')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/tbPwQA81)***

Hi now used to **both** `ID` or `Class` in **Css** if you apply `ID` or `Class` in a **Div**

**As like this**

```
#myid.myButtonClass{
// style here
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myid" class="myButtonClass">
// Some text here 
</div>
```

**More information** about **Multiple** `Class` or `id` ***[Click here](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)***

***[LIve Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/tbPwQA81)***

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
 div#myid.myButtonClass{
   //your code should be here 
}
```

use can also use this.

```
 div#myid{
   //your code should be here
 }

div.myButtonClass{
   //your code should be here
 }
```

you can use any one of the about code. The different between this two thing is, the first one is `highly specified the particular div.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply....Yes you are absolutely right however The problem is my class is already defined somewhere in css and i have to apply it in Google form css. so there are two ways either i right each and every style for that div or i can just assign my existing class in CSS file. So first question can i use my existing style sheet class for another div element? if yes how?

Comment: yes you can. Better u give separate class for each `div`. this example may be helpful to you. http://jsfiddle.net/K5aHT/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without a third party, use LESS ([http://lesscss.org/](http://lesscss.org)) or Sass (http://sass-lang.com/)